# Cannot find resource named 'Locator' thrown at design time in Blend 4, WPF4

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, mvvm-light

In the application I am developing, I have a MainWindow, which is divided in several Views. Each View is a UserControl and has its own ViewModel.

By setting a DataContext inside the UserControl, I am able to work in Expression Blend 4 with design-time data. Ops, forgot to say: I am using the "basic" Locator class, no MEF or so. Hence, in the UserControl I have something like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding MyControl, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Everything works as expected when I am designing the UserControl itself, but I am not able to get rid of some annoying exceptions that are raised in the MainWindow that contains it.

Expression Blend is saying: "Cannot find resource named 'Locator'. Resource names are case sensitive". Naturally, that's not true...

I read around that this was an old issue, now resolved.

So, does anyone know why I am getting this error?

Cheers,
Gianluca

Answer (score 2):

Your issue appears similar to the one reported here:  [Blend reports an error that it cannot find the key for ViewModelLocator](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=82284)

Comment: Hi jberger, thank you for pointing that out. Unfortunately I checked that post before, and I tried to rebuild the solution without any success. The error is still there. Eventually I'll get in touch with Laurent, but first I wanted to verify if anybody here had any idea of the cause.

Comment: Laurent seems quite good about answering questions pertaining to MVVM Light, so if you've scoured the internet with no success, then by all means I'd post your same issue on that thread.